# How to prevent build with there are tslint errors?

Tags: angular

Question
Hi everyone,

I am working in an angular 8 app that has tslint rules defined. The rules are working very nice when developers are coding but the problem that I have is the ng serve and ng build allow developers to build the app although there are TSlint errors. is there a way to force Tslint rules when the project is building so developers have to fix the TSlint errors before they can see in the browser?

best
Hmendezm

Comment: What good comes from having developers sit around waiting for their computers to finish something that will likely pass checks for the majority of the time. How is that a good use of their time? Use a computer somewhere else to run these checks when the developer is ready to share their work with others. Have you seen an open source project anywhere before? Pick one at random and see how they do it.

Answer (score -1):

Angular CLI doesn't provide a default watch param for lint as it provides for unit tests. But we can create it easily by the following:

1. Add `nodemon` as dev dependency. `npm i -D nodemon`
2. Add a script which will monitor your lint watch and if everything is fine then only it will serve in browser in package json

```
"start": "ng serve", //please add if it is missing
"serve:watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm run lint && npm run start\" --ext ts",
```

3. To monitor just run the following in console

```
npm run serve:watch
```

For every change, it will first run lint then it will refresh the browser. If anything fails then the `nodemon` will crash and you won't be able to see the changes.

Thanks